# Instantiating and Updating Several Objects

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Currently I am teaching myself Java but I came across a simple problem but have no one to ask from. From one of the exercises, I wrote a class and write a driver class that instantiates and updates several objects. I am confused by "instantiates and updates several objects." Here is what I mean: So here is my class:

```
public class PP43Car {

    private String make = "";
    private String model = "";
    private int year;

    public PP43Car(String ma, String m, int y)
    {
        make = ma;
        model = m;
        year = y;
    }

    public void setMake(String ma)
    {
        make = ma;
    }

    public String getMake()
    {
        return make;
    }

    public void setModel(String m)
    {
        model = m;
    }

    public String getModel()
    {
        return model;
    }

    public void setYear(int y)
    {
        year = y;
    }

    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String result = "Make of the vehicle: " + make +
                        " Model of the vehicle " + model + 
                        " Year of the vehicle: " + year;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Which instantiates make, model and year. Then once I was writing the driver class, the way I began was:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PP43CarTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PP43Car car1;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the model of the vehicle:");
        car1.getModel();
    }

}
```

But this class produces error and here is where I am stuck. Do I keep on going with this or is this what is meant by "instantiating and updating several objects?"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PP43CarTest {

    static PP43Car car1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        car1 = new PP43Car("Millenia", "Mazda", 2011);      
    }

}
```

If the above code is correct, then can anyone show me how I can use the Scanner class to actually get the user input and update it that way because I would like to learn that as well?

Comment: Please, try to explain better what you want to do? Do you want the user to insert the values of `make`, `model` and `year`?

Comment: @MikO For the last fragment of code I have coded, I just want to know whether that is the meaning of "instantiating and updating objects."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in your last fragment of code you are indeed instantiating an object, since you are doing:

```
car1 = new PP43Car("Millenia", "Mazda", 2011);
```

When you create a `new` object, you are creating a new **instance** of the class, so yes, you are instantiaing an object.

But you aren't updating it anywhere, because I think here updating means **modifying** the object, but you only create the object, not modify it...

Something like this would be an update:

```
car1.setYear(2013);
```

Since you are setting a different value for an attribute of the object, you are updating it...

---

EDIT: Try this code, it can't throw any exception, it's Java basics! I hope it clarifies your doubts...

```
public class PP43CarTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Declaring objects
        PP43Car car1;
        PP43Car car2;
        PP43Car car3;

        //Instantiating objects
        car1 = new PP43Car("Millenia", "Mazda", 2011);
        car2 = new PP43Car("Aaaa", "Bbb", 2012);
        car3 = new PP43Car("Ccc", "Ddd", 2012);

        //Updating objects
        car1.setMake("Xxx");
        car1.setMake("Yyy");
        car1.setYear(2013);

        //Printing objects
        System.out.println("CAR 1: " + car1.toString());
        System.out.println("CAR 2: " + car2.toString());
        System.out.println("CAR 3: " + car3.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Right. This is where I was a little confused, with modifying it. This is what I tried within the main method PP43Car car1; then I did the same thing before you posted your answer as car1.setMake(Mazda); but I got an error. Any ideas?

Comment: @HjghjgHghjgb, you added `car1.setMake(Mazda);` just after the `car1 = new PP43Car(...)` line, and it throws an error?? It shouldn't do that, what kind of Exception are you getting?

Comment: @MikeO I have no idea. I played around with it for a bit but could not remember what I did that threw the Exception. But currently trying to have the make, model, and year update anyway possible but getting nowhere. Am I doing something wrong in my driver class?

Comment: @MikeO I see my mistake now.

Comment: @HjghjgHghjgb, I'm happy it helped! Just let me remind you that you can upvote my answer in the case you found it useful... ;)